# Macro to copy entire row on editing a row

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all is there any possibilty to create a macro to copy entire row data to next sgeet when some one tried to do changes in the current sheet.

SUppose I have 10 rows, on second row I am doing some changes I need to copy the enitre row to second sheet and save the data. Can some one help me

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Worksheet_Change(...)` event function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775%28v=office.15%29.aspx

you can get to it within the excel vba editor by going to the worksheet in question in the project explorer and changing the first drop down above the script area to "Worksheet" and the second drop down to "Change". That will add the function template to the script area and you can add your logic to it there.